# Change the color of -webkit-tekst-stroke- in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a website that has some text with "text stroke", I want to change the color of that text stroke with javascript and I want four different colors.

But since it is a webkit I don't know how to do it.

This is the only thing I can think of:

````
    guessBox.style.["-webkit-text-stroke: #df0000 3px;"]
});

d2.addEventListener("click", function green() {
    guessBox.style.["-webkit-text-stroke: #005100 3px;"]
});

d3.addEventListener("click", function blue() {
    guessBox.style.["-webkit-text-stroke: #0029ff 3px;"]
});

d4.addEventListener("click", function white() {
    guessBox.style.["-webkit-text-stroke: #fff 3px;"]
});```
````

Comment: what's the value of guessBox ?

Comment: what do you mean, it's a div with some text inside, it is imported as a var.

Comment: try this ` guessBox.style = "-webkit-text-stroke: #df0000 3px;"`
Code Pen : [link](https://codepen.io/abdelhedi/pen/mdydYeR)

Comment: does it make a difference if I have ctx within the same document?

Comment: I think that there is no problem ! Please share your full code file i can't understand you very well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
guessBox.style['-webkit-text-stroke'] = '1px black';
```

Follows a full working example:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('text');
element.style['-webkit-text-stroke'] = '1px black';
console.log(element);
```

```css
.text {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" class="text">
 some text
</div>
```

Comment: does ctx change anything in this scenario?

i tried the full working example and it worked, but it doesn't work on the page.

could i be because i also use ctx for a background?